# Makefile does not track modified Python files

Tags: makefile

I currently have a project with two files `server.py` and `config.json`. I created a Makefile this way:

```
all: config server

config: config.json
    echo "config modified"

server: server.py
    echo "server modified"

.PHONY: all config server
```

When I run `make`, I expect it to display "config modified" or "server modified" only if the specified files were modified. However, both strings are displayed each time I call `make`, even if `config.json` and `server.py` have not been modified before.

I used Makefiles for other projects in C and it seemed to always work well. What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Re. `I expect it to display "config modified" or "server modified" only if the specified files were modified`: modified relative to what though since `config` and `server` are both `.PHONY` targets?

Comment: If I make a change to the files `server.py` or `config.json`: add code, change a line, remove something, etc...
I understood that I had to make them `.PHONY` because they don't represent an actual file. My only goal here is to be able to execute some code only when the content of the files in the prerequisites has changed.

Comment: But how is `make` supposed to know you've changed a file?  It needs something with which to compare that file.

Comment: I don't really get that actually. When I've used it with C files it was able to recompile only the files that have changed so I thought it would be able to do that too for other filetypes.

Comment: @rubytox _When I've used it with C files it was able to recompile only the files that have changed so I thought it would be able to do that too for other filetypes_ When you used it with C files your targets were real files (`.o` or executable) and you did not declare them as phony. What you show is completely different and this has nothing to do with file types: your `config` and `server` targets are **not** files and you declared them as **phony**...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to decide if a prerequisite (e.g. `server.py`) is newer or not than the target (e.g. `server`) `make` needs two timestamps to compare: one for the prerequisite and one for the target. This means that your prerequisites and targets **must be files**. If your targets are not files, `make` has only one timestamp left. How do you want it to decide if this single timestamp is new or not? By comparing it to what? Current time? It would always be old. What else?

Moreover, you declared `config` and `server` as phony targets. In other words you told `make` that these targets shall always be remade, even if a file with that name exists.

If you want `make` to decide alone whether a target must be remade or not you must stick to the canonical `make` rule:

```
target-file: prerequisite-file...
    recipe
```

This way `make` compares the last modification times of the target file and its prerequisite files and knows whether the target file is older than some prerequisites or not, that is, whether it shall be remade or not. In your case this could be something like:

```
all: config server

config: config.json
    echo "config modified"
    touch $@

server: server.py
    echo "server modified"
    touch $@

.PHONY: all
```

The `touch $@` recipe updates the last modification time of the target file (or creates it) and now, each time it runs, `make` can do its job properly. And yes, it forces you to accept the existence of these two files, but really, think about it, there is no other solution. These two files are a kind of `make` memory: they record when each recipe was last run.

If you don't want to see these files you can hide them (e.g. by naming them `.config` and `.server` if you are under some UNIX-like OS).

You can even create them in a dedicated sub-directory for easier cleaning:

```
TMPDIR := .tmpdir

all: $(TMPDIR)/config $(TMPDIR)/server

$(TMPDIR)/config: config.json
    echo "config modified"
    mkdir -p $(@D); touch $@

$(TMPDIR)/server: server.py
    echo "server modified"
    mkdir -p $(@D); touch $@

.PHONY: all clean

clean:
    rm -rf $(TMPDIR)
```

Comment: Thank you really much for your answer, I think I understand better how it works!